# Loading JSON data into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new to using pandas and python I am trying to load JSON files that I have into a jupyter notebook. I am having difficulties with getting the data into a Dataframe.

```py
    os.chdir('M:\JT\Voyages Data')
    with open('M:\JT\Voyages Data\Data.json') as data:
        data = json.load(data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am unable to print this out as I keep getting the error that

`arrays must all be the same length`

EDIT***

sorry for not including sooner here is a copy of some of the data from the JSON file,

```
{'columns': ['total', 'results', 'site'],
 'index': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'data': [[157773,
   [{'load_zone': 'East Mediterranean',
     'load_country': 'Turkey',
     'load_port': 'Bandirma',
     'load_berth': None,
     'load_anchorage': None,
     'load_draft': 7.9,
     'load_duration': None,
     'load_full_duration': None,
     'load_wait_duration': None,
     'load_full_wait_duration': None,
     'load_start_date': '2013-07-16 03:43:19',
     'load_end_date': '2013-07-17 03:43:19',
     'discharge_zone': 'North West Africa',
     'discharge_country': 'Morocco',
     'discharge_port': 'Safi',
     'discharge_berth': 'Quai De Commerce',
     'discharge_anchorage': None,
     'discharge_draft': 4.5,
     'discharge_duration': 1734,
     'discharge_full_duration': 2406,
     'discharge_wait_duration': 0,
     'discharge_full_wait_duration': 0,
     'discharge_start_date': '2013-08-15 08:28:59',
     'discharge_end_date': '2013-08-16 13:23:00',
     'commodity': 'Steam Coal',
     'commodity_group': 'Coal',
     'charterer': None,
     'vsl_imo': 9045742,
     'vsl_dwt': 6584,
     'vsl_name': 'OSTRA',
     'vsl_type': 'Multi-Purpose',
     'vsl_max_speed': 0,
     'vsl_max_draft': 7.6,
     'has_part_voy': 1,
     'voy_draft_diff': 3.4,
     'voy_load_draft_ratio': 103.947,
     'voy_intake_mt': 5926,
     'voy_avg_speed': 11.26,
     'voy_speed_ratio': None,
     'voy_top_speed': 13.38,
     'voy_duration': 45220,
     'voy_sea_duration': 42813,
     'bunk_duration': 0,
     'bunk_wait_duration': 0,
     'blackout_duration': 18645,
     'shipyard_duration': 0,
     'previous_zone': 'Black Sea',
     'previous_port': 'Efesan Port',
     'previous_berth': None,
     'previous_operation': 'disch',
     'next_zone': 'North West Africa',
     'next_port': 'Jorf Lasfar',
     'next_berth': 'Berth 2 Phosphate / Fertilizers',
     'next_operation': 'load'},
    {'load_zone': 'North Coast South America',
     'load_country': 'Colombia',
     'load_port': 'Puerto Nuevo - Colombia',
     'load_berth': 'Puerto Nuevo Coal Pier',
     'load_anchorage': None,
     'load_draft': 18.1,
     'load_duration': 4685,
     'load_full_duration': 4685,
     'load_wait_duration': 421,
     'load_full_wait_duration': 421,
     'load_start_date': '2013-07-25 15:17:47',
     'load_end_date': '2013-07-28 21:22:56',
     'discharge_zone': 'Antwerp Rotterdam Amsterdam Ghent',
     'discharge_country': 'Netherlands',
     'discharge_port': 'Rotterdam',
     'discharge_berth': 'EMO - Europees Massagoed- Overslagbedrijf ',
     'discharge_anchorage': None,
     'discharge_draft': 9.9,
     'discharge_duration': 1112,
     'discharge_full_duration': 1112,
     'discharge_wait_duration': 0,
     'discharge_full_wait_duration': 0,
     'discharge_start_date': '2013-08-15 08:45:24',
     'discharge_end_date': '2013-08-16 03:17:29',
     'commodity': 'Steam Coal',
     'commodity_group': 'Coal',
     'charterer': None,
     'vsl_imo': 9581760,
     'vsl_dwt': 181415,
     'vsl_name': 'Sea Triumph',
     'vsl_type': 'Bulk Carrier',
     'vsl_max_speed': 0,
     'vsl_max_draft': 18.3,
     'has_part_voy': 0,
     'voy_draft_diff': 8.2,
     'voy_load_draft_ratio': 98.9071,
     'voy_intake_mt': 172851,
     'voy_avg_speed': 12.19,
     'voy_speed_ratio': None,
     'voy_top_speed': 13.65,
     'voy_duration': 30960,
     'voy_sea_duration': 25162,
     'bunk_duration': 0,
     'bunk_wait_duration': 0,
     'blackout_duration': 0,
     'shipyard_duration': 0,
     'previous_zone': 'Antwerp Rotterdam Amsterdam Ghent',
     'previous_port': 'Rotterdam',
     'previous_berth': 'EMO - Europees Massagoed- Overslagbedrijf ',
     'previous_operation': 'disch',
     'next_zone': 'North Coast South America',
     'next_port': 'Puerto Nuevo - Colombia',
     'next_berth': 'Puerto Nuevo Coal Pier',
     'next_operation': 'load'},
```

Comment: You will need to show the contents of your data files (or at least a sample) to allow people to debug the problem. For safety/clarity you might also want to not overwrite `data` (the file handle) with `data` (the json).

Answer (score 1):

You have defined sixteen elements in your index, but what you've provided to us in the `data` does not contain sixteen objects, at least what we can see of it.

1. You may want to read the pandas documentation for the `.read_json()` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html
2. Carefully examine the source JSON file to ensure it is shaped in a way that pandas can consume. It looks like you're trying to use the 'split' formatted JSON.